# Need to know how: $L^{p}$ convergence for function.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I feel terrible at the moment as I have exhausted everything possible to understand this and I am still stuck. I have looked everywhere for some sort of resource to the concept at hand, and yet, they all seem out of context. Thus, I am asking if someone can provide me with a worked solution so that I can understand what is happening.

I have proved many types of convergences, and I am left to investigate $L^{P}$ convergence. The function is:

$f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}+sin(k)}{k^{2}}$,

where $f_{k}(x)= \frac{x^{k}+sin(k)}{k^{2}}$

It has a domain in [-1,1] and converges uniformly (and thus pointwisely) in this domain. My understanding is that we say $f(x)$ converges in the $L^{P}$ sense if

$\underset{k \to \infty}{lim} ||f(x)-f_{k}(x)||=0$.

However, if $f(x)$ is my series function, should $f_{k}(x)$ be the values after the sigma, or the partial sums? Can someone please show how this works.

Thank you all so much in advanced.

Comment: It looks as if you've misread the statement of the problem, because what you've written doesn't make sense.  You've defind $f(x)$ but not $f_k(x)$, but your definition of $f(x)$ has a $k$ in it, so that's probably supposed to be $f_k(x)$.  What's $f(x)$?  And the question you probably want to be asking is whether $f_k$ converges to $f$ in the $L^p$ sense, not whether $f(x)$ converges.  Please edit your question so that it makes sense.  (Once you've done that, here's a hint: can you show that uniform convergence implies $L^p$ convergence?)

Comment: Either $f_k$ should be a partial sum or you should have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|f(x)-\sum_{k=1}^nf_k(x)\right\|=0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\|f_k\|_p
&=\left(\int_{-1}^1\left|\frac{x^k+\sin(k)}{k^2}\right|^p\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\\
&\le\left(\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{2}{k^2}\right)^p\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\\
&=\frac{2^{1+1/p}}{k^2}
\end{align}
$$
and use [Minkowski's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you copied your problem incorrectly. It should probably be $f_k(x)=\frac{x^k+\sin(k)}{k^2}$. You can use dominated convergence to show that $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|f_k\|_{L^p}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

I know I answered your previous question but I think I can help here, now it has been rephrased, so: let $f_k(x)=\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}$

Under the $L^p$ norm (to the power of $p$) we have:

$\|f\|_p^p=\int_{-1}^{1}|\frac{x^k+sin(k)}{k^2}|^pdx\leq\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2}{k^{2p}}dx=\frac{4}{k^{2p}}$, thus:

$\lim_{k\to\infty}\|f\|_p\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}(\frac{4}{k^{2p}})^{\frac{1}{p}}=0$

thus this sequence converges to $0$ in $L^p$.